# MySQL Can't create a new thread (errno 12)

Tags: php, mysql, centos, performance

I'm runnning MySQL 5.0.45/ PHP Version 5.2.6 / CentOS with Plesk.

I get occasionaly a burst of "Can't create a new thread (errno 12); if you are not out of available memory, you can consult the manual for a possible OS-dependent bug"

Global memory is not the issue since I have about 620M free.

Anyone know what could be the cause for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [bug 20815](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=20815), mysql is using too much stack space for threads. Try upgrading to at least 5.0.48 or 5.1.21.

Answer (score 0):

Any ulimit style restrictions?

Otherwise AppArmor or things like that come to mind.

Comment: I don't think its AppArmor or something similar. it happens occasionaly not always

How can I check for ulimit style restrictions and whether my setting exceeds them?